# axios and jQuery post format

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, vue.js, axios

Testing two methods in Vue: one with axios and one with jQuery:

```
axios.post('./test.cshtml',  { para: 'test_Axios', action: 'test' })
$.post('./test.cshtml', { para: 'test_JQ', action: 'test' });
```

According to Stackify the posted data are on these formats:

- with axios:  Post data: `{"para":"selectSyklus_POST_Axios","action":"test"}`
- with jQuery: Post data: `para=selectSyklus_POST_JQ&action=test`

Target cshtml can read the jQuery format with `var action = Request["action"];`
but how do I read the axios (json?) format? Or send the axios post data in same format as jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or send the axios post data in same format as jQuery?

By default, Axios sends JSON. But you can tell it to send URI-encoded data (the default of jQuery, and indeed, forms in general) instead. From [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format):

> **Browser**
>
> In a browser, you can use the `URLSearchParams` API as follows:
>
> ```
> const params = new URLSearchParams();
> params.append('param1', 'value1');
> params.append('param2', 'value2');
> axios.post('/foo', params);
> ```
>
> Note that `URLSearchParams` is not supported by all browsers (see [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams)), but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) available (make sure to polyfill the global environment).

Comment: Thank you. Worked!

Comment: ...but not in IE11.

Comment: Did you use the polyfill?

Comment: Tried the index.js from https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill , <script src="index.js"></script> in the cshtml-file but still no success.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't use the polyfill that axios specifically mentions? https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params/blob/master/build/url-search-params.js.

Comment: No reason. Used this and everything works fine now. Thanks again!